# Magento 2.2 any issue will arise if we truncate import export history?

Tags: magento2.2, indexer, import-products

If I truncate `import_history` table from database in Magento 2.2 version.

But thing is that some of the values in `execution_time` column it's showing as `In Progress` which seems to that product import is still running on in the backend.

I checked the code in the `magento-import-export` module and `magento-indexer` but not found any thing.

Anyone has faced this kind of issues?

Comment: have you resolved this issue, I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: `In Progress` is a value of `Execution time` which will only change if the import process is completed. So it should not create further issues. Same CSV may resolve the issue. During the import process, the table `importexport_importdata` will have entries in batches.

Comment: what is the solution for this? for some of our product import is "in progress" from last one month.

Comment: and is it not completing at all

Comment: `In Progress` may not resume the import process. To resolve this, you can re-import the same CSV which stuck in `In Progress`. The filename will be in `imported_file` column of the `import_history` tbl.